# AngularJS 2 Dynamically search div for id and add new div

Tags: angular

How I can search for an item by `id`, and add other elements inside, programmatically?

I searched the web, and on the website of angularjs2 but I can not find any example, not if the fault is that I am doing wrong or there to do otherwise to do this.

```
@Component({
    selector: "testcomponente",
    template: `
    //other code  
    <div class = "container" id = "table1" >

    </div>
    `
 })


export class Mov {
.//
t(){
   var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
   iDiv.id = 'block';
   iDiv.className = 'block';
   var t : any = document.getElementsById('table1').appendChild(iDiv); <-- error
   .//
}
```

I have this error when compiling:

```
error TS2339: Property 'getElementsById' does not exist on type 'Document'.
```

any example or link is appreciated, and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one selector `id` is allowed on page as per HTML standards. So you need to correct your method name should be `getElementsById` singular instead of plural.

Change to

```
document.getElementById('table1')
```

instead of

```
document.getElementsById('table1')
```

But technically, if you wanted add the number of element, dynamically on demand you could render that using `ngFor` directive here.

**Code**

```
import { NgFor } from 'angular2/common'

@Component({
    selector: "testcomponente",
    template: `
    <button type="button" (click)="addElement()">Add Element</button>
    //other code  
    <div class = "container" id = "table1" >
       <div *ngFor="item in items"> Repeatative Item content </div>
    </div>
    `,
    directives: ['NgFor']
})

export class Mov {
    items: Array<number>();
    count: number = 1;

    addElement(){
       items.push(++number);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to do is press a button to add a div, this would be a, correct approach to do this?

Comment: @AngelAngel Glad to know that. Thanks :)